# How do I update macOS App Store apps to the latest compatible version?

Tags: mojave, xcode, mac-appstore, software-update, imovie

I have rather belatedly (March 2021) updated my macBook to Mojave.  Because I depend on Aperture and other 32-bit apps I can't update to Catalina.

`brew doctor` tells me:

```
Warning: Your Xcode (10.1) is too outdated.
Please update to Xcode 11.3.1 (or delete it).
Xcode can be updated from the App Store.
```

But unfortunately trying to update Xcode or other out-of-date apps, including iMovie, using the App store:

- The Updates tab (⌘7) says "No Updates.  All your apps are up to date".
- When I go to page for Xcode and click "update", it tells me "We could not complete your update.  Xcode can’t be installed on “Macintosh HD” because macOS version 10.15.4 or later is required."  I get similar messages for iMovie.
- The profile tab (⌘0) shows both Xcode and iMovie in the list of purchases, but the buttons next to each just say "Open".

  - Sometimes, if I wait a while, the button next to Xcode (but not iMovie) will change to say "update", and when I click on it I get a dialog that says "Download an older version of Xcode?  The current version requires OS X 10.15.4 or later, but you can download the last compatible version"—but when I click "Download" the same dialog reappears again immediately.

    [image: Download an older version of Xcode? The current version requires OS X 10.15.4 or later, but you can download the last compatible version.]

How can I install the latest compatible version of apps originally installed through the App Store on older versions of macOS?

Comment: Have you considered uninstalling Xcode, per the message? The alternative is to install the command line tools themselves - which may have more flexibility with older OS’s. I assume it will prompt you to use “xcode-select —install” once you try to use brew again. Also note that brew doctor is for debugging, if everything works for you then you can ignore it.

Comment: I finally upgraded to 10.14.6 from 10.12.6 in January 2021. I also stumbled getting the right Xcode. We need to go back to Xcode 10.3 for the correct platform and SDK. This page helped enormously: https://xcodereleases.com/

Comment: @JBallin: that is indeed what I have done for Xcode.  But there is no equivalent outside-App-store route for iMovie that I know of.

Comment: Another issue here is that Homebrew only supports the last 3 versions of macOS and so does not support Mojave.

Answer (score 1):

re: "How can I install the latest compatible version of apps originally installed through the App Store on older versions of macOS?" -- When I went to Mojave and got that message ("No Updates. All your apps are up to date"), hitting command-R refreshed the page and all the updates became available. (I never would have figured that one out, it doesn't even look like something "refreshable", I got the tip from some other page.)

Answer (score 0):

Xcode can be updated by downloading the appropriate release from [the Additional Downloads](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=xcode) section of https://developer.apple.com/ - for Mojave, the latest compatible version is 10.3.1, or consult [this Xcode compatibility table](https://xcodereleases.com/) for other macOS versions (as suggested by aMike—thanks!)

It can be installed simply by uncompressing the downloaded `.xip` file and then dragging Xcode.app to `/Applications/`.